# Updating scala breeze matrix for point with x,y coordinates (NOT length of rows and cols)

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I'm new to Scala (Python background) and trying to implement a Quadtree for my sparse data and attempting to use `Breeze` to do so (although if you have a better suggestion, I'm totally open to it).

My problem is this: I need to know how to update a matrix at (x,y) without recursing through simply `i <- 0 until matrix.rows` because I don't have the values for all the rows and columns, I only have specific xs and ys. If this is unclear here's what I mean: In the `breeze` documentation, you normally see something like this

```
val r = new scala.util.Random(100)
    for(i <-0 until Matrix.rows)
        for(j <- 0 until Matrix.cols)
            Matrix(i,j) = r.nextInt
    return Matrix
```

This is fine and dandy if I had a value for EVERY value in the matrix, but I don't. Instead what I'm working with is something like this.

```
val points: Array[Double] = Array(3.0, 5.0, 8.0)
val xs: Array[Double] = Array(2.0, 5.0, 6.0)
val ys: Array[Double] = Array(3.0, 4.0, 6.0)
```

where I want `matrix(2,3) = 3.0`

Where I know that my matrix should be a 6x6 matrix `DenseMatrix[Double](6,6)`.

Assuming that I begin with a matrix of zeros (`DenseMatrix.zeros(6,6)`) how can I insert my `points` using my `xs` and `ys` rather than `.rows` and `.cols`?

I have tried this:
(where `emptym` is a 6x6 matrix of zeros)

```
val matrix = for {
     | x <- xs
     | y <- ys
     | p <- points
     | } yield (emptym(x.toInt,y.toInt) = p)
```

which gives me all kinds of errors :/

I was thinking maybe I could do this with some kind of `map` function, because I want to return a val for this but I'm new enough to scala that I cant quite figure out how to do this.

Please help me figure this out. Thanks! :)

Edit -- Ideally, I'm hoping for a more FP solution that doesn't have to loop through the matrix and update it. I'd like to create a new matrix. I'm thinking something like this, but can't get it to work:

```
val newMatrix = oldMatrix.map(xs, ys, points => oldMatirx(x,y) = point)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *update* method, where you can pass the row number, col number and the value to update a cell in the matrix:

```
val mat = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](6,6)
for (i <- 0 until xs.length) {
  mat.update(xs(i).toInt - 1, ys(i).toInt - 1, points(i))
}
```

Print the matrix out:

```
for (i <- 0 until mat.rows){
  for(j <- 0 until mat.cols) {
    print(mat(i, j) + " ")
  }
  println()
}

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!! I tried it out and it worked :). This answer worked but its pretty iterative, and I'm looking for a more functional programming option. Can this simply not be done with scala breeze, do you think?